# E-mail is verified, but I still can't send emails using Amazon SES

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have an e-mail for sure **verified** in the AWS console and I didn't ask for production access yet. I'm trying to send emails using my node applications in the localhost and I keep getting the error that the e-mail address is not verified.

I'm using the code provided by AWS documentation.

```
var params = {
  RawMessage: { // required
  Data: 'BASE64_ENCODED_STRING', // required
},
 Destinations: [
   'STRING_VALUE',
   // ... more items ...
 ],
 Source: 'STRING_VALUE',
};
ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the localhost was considered a different region by AWS and I had to verify the e-mail again in the other region.